# HTML and CSS background-image

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, image, background

i'n a mine rails app i'm changing the html part of a page (localhost:3000/feeds), in the file index.html.erb i set the background this way

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
  <html>

    <head>

      <style type="text/css">
          body
          {
            background-image:url("../../assets/images/wwi.jpg");
          }
        </style>

    </head>
</html>
```

the directory are set this way:

```
->app
 ->assets
  ->images
    ->wwi.jpg
 ->views
  ->feeds
   ->index.html.erb
```

but when i start the rails server and the go to localist:3000/feeds there's no background (i had no problem for background-color)

Comment: You sure the path is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using rails asset pipeline by writing your css inside views. If you look at docs it says

`Asset pipeline concatenate assets, which can reduce the number of requests that a browser makes to render a web page. Web browsers are limited in the number of requests that they can make in parallel, so fewer requests can mean faster loading for your application`

*So you should use it and for that first of all remove all the styles from your layout or views and you need to include rails application.css in your layout file by

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
```

*This tag will make rails use look for your styles inside **assets/stylesheets/application.css***. Now you need to require the style.css.erb you just made to include your styles by

```
*= require style
```

Now inside your style.css.erb you can have your style like this:

```
body{
  background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'wwi.png' %>)
}
```

Update:

If you want to use sass instead then your file would be **style.css.scss** and can use rails **`image-url`** helper, so you can do:

```
body{
  background-image: image-url('wwi.png');
}
```

For more details refer to [**`rails asset pipeline`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Answer (score 0):

When using the assets pipeline, path should be relative to the root

`background-image:url("/assets/wwi.jpg");`

images is assumed.

Also you can use the assets helper

`<%= asset_path 'wwi.png' %>`

I recommend you read the documentation of the assets pipeline

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: The first example will not work in production mode (with md5 fingerprints added to filenames). Using `asset_path` should be recommended.

Comment: and where and how do i use

    <%= asset_path 'wwi.png' %>